# accessing indexes of tf.data.Dataset for deleting and appending data elements

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am currently working on a research project in which I have to append my training set after some epochs and delete some samples from test set after evaluation. Currently there is no way through with which I can access the records (placed at specific indexes) in tfrecord file to delete or append. Since tfrecords offer very fast training so I avoid using generators. Any suggestion to access tfrecord file in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have to append my training set after some epochs

You can use `repeat(n)` to repeat the dataset for `n` epochs then `concatenate(new_dataset)` to append some extra data. So, in order to append the new data after 15 epochs, for example, we could do:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('filepath.tfrecord')
new_data = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('filepath_of_records_to_append.tfrecord') # or any other dataset from generator or whatever!

dataset = dataset.repeat(15).concatenate(new_data)
```

> and delete some samples from test set

You can't easily delete from the original tfrecord file using the tf.data API (you'd effectively have to write a new tfrecord file with the records omitted) so perhaps instead you'd find it useful to just construct a `tf.data` Dataset and ignore or skip the records you want omitted? This is much more straightforward and can be done using `take()` & `skip()`.

So, for example, if I wanted to skip the records at index 4, 7,8,9 & 10 I could do the following:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('filepath.tfrecord')

dataset = dataset.take(4).skip(1).take(2).skip(4)
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using a similar method for concatenating the new tfrecords but for deleting, I cant opt to make a new tfrecord since the datasets from which elements are to be removed are quite large and I cant afford to spend a long time in making tfrecords in middle of training, so the dataset from which elements are to be removed, I used generator for that purpose (although its a bottleneck but takes shorter time as comapred to making tfrecord file). Anyhow, I feel tfrecords should have some indexing mechanism

Comment: @samra I believe the tfrecord format is optimised for fast sequential reads so can't support indexing directly. I guess their primary purpose is to try to facilitate moving bulk data from disk to processor as fast as possible rather than to support random access.

Comment: The second part of your solution is not correct, as it does not skip the desired records, but instead leaves you with an empty dataset. In dataset.take(4).skip(1).take(2).skip(4) the last part takes only 2 records, and then skips 4 of these 2 records, so the result is empty. Concatenation can be used instead, e.g. for skipping index 4 and 7:
dataset.take(4).concatenate(dataset.skip(5).take(2)).concatenate(dataset.skip(8))